# Get Client IP Address in Rails and Output to View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, client, ip-address, ipv6

In Ruby on Rails, how can I get the IP Address of a client? I want that when a user visits a certain page, Rails gets their ip address and displays it on the screen.

In my controller I've tried:

```
request.remote_ip
```

but it is returning `::1` which to my knowledge is IPv6. I would like to get the IPv4 address of the client. How can I achieve this? I would only need to do this once per client since I'm only checking the ip address of the first device that they use to visit my page.

Comment: IPv6 is the way to go - why do you want to change this? There's a good reason why the net is moving from IPv4 to IPv6... Also, the `remote_ip` is (or should be) a best guess scenario. In real world communication, it's likely that your application will be behind a proxy layer (i.e. nginx, etc') and the remote IP address will be guessed according to the HTTP headers.

Comment: @Myst in my environment, IPv6 is not used and can cause connectivity problems with the users while connected to our VPN.

Comment: it sounds like the IPv4 support might be the issue to resolve... people connecting from home will probably be using IPv6 with their ISP. If not today, than pretty soon. It seems to me that using the IPv4 for anything other than logging might propagate the issue... especially if it's used to confirm VPN access, which would introduce security concerns regarding HTTP header forgery.

Comment: @Myst the VPN has its own network adapter in which it uses IPv4. For any non-work related app, whatever the OS has as default (IPv6) will take precedence. We aren't truly disabling IPv6. We are just using IPv4 precedence through the apps and vpn themselves. If someone were to complain to us that they are experiencing network connectivity issues (which has happened before), then unchecking IPv6 in the network adapters will fix that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either

1. `request.ip` that returns the ip, whether it is a local proxy ip
   address (localhost address) or not.
2. `request.remote_ip` is smarter and gets the ip address of the client
   outside of local proxies and this is the best that is an interpretation of all the available IP address information and it will make a best-guess.

> (`request.remote_ip`)Determines originating IP address. REMOTE_ADDR is the standard but
>   will fail if the user is behind a proxy. HTTP_CLIENT_IP and/or
>   HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR are set by proxies so check for these if
>   REMOTE_ADDR is a proxy. HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR may be a comma- delimited
>   list in the case of multiple chained proxies; the last address which
>   is not trusted is the originating IP.

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain that `::1` is not sufficient?  That is the local host; if you publish the site to anywhere requiring layer 3 transport it should render the appropriate IPv4 or IPv6 address respectively.

In short, if you disable your local IPv6 stack 127.0.0.1 would render.

Comment: And how would I disable IPv6? I've already unchecked the box in the network adapter properties for all my network adapters.

Comment: It's kind of involved in Windows, http://www.techunboxed.com/2012/08/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-8.html

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't have to disable it, it's kind of a lot of work to go through to see 127.0.0.1  What I describe should work (i.e. just deploy the application somewhere other than localhost).